# String comparison working on DBSet but not on LIST item in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

In our C# application we need to compare GUID, In Database it is UPPERCASE but suppose in Code it is in LOWERCASE.

I understand we can handle this by string.Compare or string.Equals but I would like to understand following scenario.

```
var myInstanceId ='GUID';
```

Following line do perfect comparison,

```
var applicationSettings = db.ApplicationSettingsSet
  .Where(x => x.myInstanceId == myInstanceId).ToList();
```

may be due to db.ApplicationSettingsSet is EF DB entity

```
  public DbSet<ApplicationSetting> ApplicationSettingSet { get; set; }
```

But Somehow following code not working where

```
applicationSettingCategory.ApplicationSettings = applicationSettings
  .Where(x =>  x.myInstanceId == myInstanceId );
```

May be due to now comparison is happen on LIST of ApplicationSettings & not on DBSet.

What is actual reason of this behavior?

Comment: What is the data type of `KcsInstanceId`, is it `GUID` ?

Comment: Probably your data server is case insensitive. If you are using Sql Server, that will be the issue.

Comment: as long as both are `Guid` types, you don't need to worry about data conversion

Comment: @Habib yes, but we cast it into String

Comment: @Kcsss, so in EF6 query, you are comparing Guids and in the other query  you are comparing strings ?

Comment: @Mathew I understand comparison part, but I want to understand why it is working on DBSET & not on Item in LIST

Comment: Before downvote please see code carefully, I think enough information is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is linq to sql:

```
var applicationSettings = db.ApplicationSettingsSet.Where(x => x.myInstanceId == myInstanceId).ToList();
```

translates compare statement to SQL and actual comparison is done in database. Depending if database is case sensitive it can change, so I assume your database is not case sensitive.

Where this is linq to objects:

```
applicationSettingCategory.ApplicationSettings = applicationSettings.Where(x =>  x.myInstanceId == myInstanceId );
```

Here you have to specify comparison to be not case sensitive like for `String.Equals`.

Comment: Thanks :) This is the only thing which I want to be sure about @Mateusz